# Reading columns of data into arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am new to Python. I use Fortran to generate the data file I wish to read. For many reasons I would like to use python to calculate averages and statistics on the data rather than fortan.

I need to read the entries in the the first three rows as strings, and then the data which begins in the fourth row onwards as numbers. I don't need the first column, but I do need the rest of the columns each as their own arrays.

```
# Instantaneous properties
# MC_STEP              Density          Pressure      Energy_Total
#                  (molec/A^3)             (bar)      (kJ/mol)-Ext
       0    0.34130959E-01    0.52255964E+05    0.26562549E+04
      10    0.34130959E-01    0.52174646E+05    0.25835710E+04
      20    0.34130959E-01    0.52050492E+05    0.25278775E+04
```

And the data goes on for thousands, and sometimes millions of lines.

I have tried the following, but run into problems since I can't analyze the lists I have made, and I can't seem to convert them to arrays. I would prefer however to just create arrays to begin with, but if I can convert my lists to arrays that would work too. In my method I get an error when i try to use an element in one of the lists, i.e. Energy(i)

```
with open('nvt_test_1.out.box1.prp1') as f:
    Title = f.readline()
    Properties = f.readline()
    Units = f.readline()
    Density = []
    Pressure = []
    Energy = []
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        Density.append(row[1])
        Pressure.append(row[2])
        Energy.append(row[3])
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What error do you get? Are you actually writing `Energy(i)`? Because if so, that's [not the correct way to access your elements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists); try `Energy[i]`

Comment: also note that in python, capitalized names are usually reserved for classes. Convention is to use [all-lowercase, underscore-separated names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) for regular variables and methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use pandas module for this task:

```
import pandas as pd

In [9]: df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', delim_whitespace=True, 
                         comment='#', skiprows=3,header=None,
                         names=['MC_STEP','Density','Pressure','Energy_Total'])
```

Data Frame:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   MC_STEP   Density   Pressure  Energy_Total
0        0  0.034131  52255.964     2656.2549
1       10  0.034131  52174.646     2583.5710
2       20  0.034131  52050.492     2527.8775
```

Average values for all columns:

```
In [11]: df.mean()
Out[11]:
MC_STEP            10.000000
Density             0.034131
Pressure        52160.367333
Energy_Total     2589.234467
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider a `list` in Python like an `array` in other languages and it's very optimised. If you have some special needs there is an array type available but rarely used, alternatively the `numpy.array` that is designed for scientific computation; you have to install the [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org) package for that.

Before performing calculations cast the string to a float, like in `energy.append(float(row[3]))`

Maybe do it at once using `map` function:

```
row = map(float, line.split())
```

Last, as @Hamms said, access the elements by using square brackets `e = energy[i]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the csv module's DictReader to read each row into a dictionary, as follows:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=r'\s+', fieldnames=('MC_STEP', 'DENSITY', 'PRESSURE', 'ENERGY_TOTAL')
    for row in reader:
        Density.append(float(row['DENSITY'])
        Pressure.append(float(row['PRESSURE'])
        Energy.append(float(row['ENERGY_TOTAL'])
```

Ofcourse this assumes that the file is formatted more like a CSV (that is, no comments). If the file does have comments at the top, you can skip them before initializing the DictReader as follows:

```
next(f)
```